# Is it illegal for a European to be paid for giving financial advice to people in the US?

Tags: international, finance

I live in a country in the EU in which giving financial advice, such as stock tips, and getting paid for this is perfectly legal for a private individual.

Let's say I have a friend in the US who asks me to look at his stock portfolio and says he'll give me money if I say which stocks to throw out and suggest some other stocks.

As far as I know there are some issues with giving financial advice in the US. Could this get me in trouble? Are there other countries where this could be a problem? Thank you for the help.